# Why am I getting "cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code" when I'm using cv2.BackgroundSubtractorKNN() in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, background-subtraction

A simple program to show the feed from my webcam is running fine. I'm getting the error only when I try to run `cv2.BackgroundSubtractorKNN()` within the loop.
I have applied the following fix:
Uninstalled the latest version of OpenCV (which I was using) and installed an older version 4.5.4. But the error still persists.
Here's my code and the corresponding messages in the terminal.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
mog = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorKNN()


while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = mog.apply(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Message in terminal

```
PS D:\Python ground up\Open_CV> python -u "d:\Python ground up\Open_CV\backgroundsub.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python ground up\Open_CV\backgroundsub.py", line 7, in <module>
    fgmask = mog.apply(frame)
cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's `createBackgroundSubtractorKNN` not `BackgroundSubtractorKNN`

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but more of a comment. If you want to post an actual answer, then please read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Otherwise if you just wanted to post a comment, then please be patient until you get enough reputation to do so. Posting comments as answers will lead to them being downvoted, closed, and making you loose reputation, so it takes longer until you can post comments.

Comment: Yes I have. Same error.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html

Comment: Sorry I didn't have enough reputation to make comment. Also I think I found an answer so I changed the post

Comment: For a simple way to improve your answer: Don't say that you "*think*" what it should be. Just state that it *should* be. Then tell us *why* it should be like that. What is the difference between using ``createBackgroundSubtractorKNN` and `BackgroundSubtractorKNN`. What is it that makes `createBackgroundSubtractorKNN`  work but `BackgroundSubtractorKNN` not work?